# GET params are not recieved in Flask-RESTful + webargs

Tags: flask, flask-restful, webargs

I'm using `Resource` class from flask restful and `use_kwargs` decorator for get method. Here is the code:

```
@api.resource('/route/')
class API(Resource):
    @use_kwargs({'param': fields.Str(missing='default_val')}
    def get(self, param):
        return {'param': param}
```

But I can not pass parameters via URL. It always returns missing value. 
These URL's don't work:

```
 /route?param=smth
 /route/?param=smth
```

Same for `use_args`. However I can see my params in `flask.request.args`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since webargs 6, you need to specify the location explicitly.

```
@api.resource('/route/')
class API(Resource):
    @use_kwargs({'param': fields.Str(missing='default_val')}, location="query")
    def get(self, param):
        return {'param': param}
```

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/62503287/4653485.